# Azure Traffic manager with more than one Web App in the same region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'd need to use Traffic Manager to route traffic to three app services I have in the same region (one app service with three instances won't work, I need more control on the load balancing).

I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types#can-i-use-traffic-manager-with-more-than-one-web-app-in-the-same-region) that this is possibile

I tried to set up the app services in different app service plans but still I cannot assign the same domain to more than one app service. In the doc I read "scale unit" but I do not know what it is, any ideas? Basically I cannot create two App Services in the same region with the same domain assigned to them.

Comment: When they talk about scale units I think they are talking about the VMs that run Azure App Service. You can see the URL of the scale unit if you run `nslookup yoursite.azurewebsites.net`. You will get an answer like `waws-prod-am2-077.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net`. That means the Web Apps can't be in the same App Service Plan.

Comment: Instead of multiple App Service Plans in the same Region, you should use manual scaling or Autoscale to have Multiple Instances of your app in the Region.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not really sure that you need more App Service Plans, but let's say you need.

Than what you will be looking at is [nested profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-nested-profiles).

There is also [good documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types) which explains the limitations:

> Each Traffic Manager profile can have at most one Web App endpoint
>   from each Azure region. To work around for this constraint, you can
>   configure a Web App as an External endpoint. For more information, see
>   the FAQ.

and workarounds for some of them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types#faq).

The scale unit, is the one that bugs you. @juunas is on the correct path to help you find your scale unit. However AppServicePlan is not a single VM, but that's another subject.

So the basic idea:

- you create an app service plan
- you create a web app within it
- you rung the `nslookup yoursite.azurewebsites.net` to discover your **real** DNS name. Just like @juunas pointed, it would be something like `waws-prod-am2-077.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net`. The `waws-prod-am2-077` is your scale unit.

You repeat these steps until you discover that your App Service Plans run on different scale units.

It is really pity that this is not documented anywhere. And no, there is no easier way to check the scale unit of an app service plan. Neither is there easier way to deploy multiple app service plans across different scale units.

On the other hand, having your app service plans spread across different scale units will give your app much better resiliasncy against partial service outages :)

Comment: just tried this and you're right but wow, managed to get the first app service in a new scale unit, I have to get another 3, at least, of them, it is going to take forever. One question, why you say that you are not sure we need diffrent app service plans? Do you mean we could go to a new scale unit also using the same app service plan (this would make sense)?

Comment: Hi. What I meant is - why don't you just use a single App Service Plan for your app. Will make things for you so much simpler. When you need to scale just one app - then all the apps will leverage the power. You do not lose anything.
And no - you cannot span single App Service Plan across different scale units.

Comment: Because I need to be in different scale units to assign the same domain to different App Service and you say that I cannot span single App Service Plan across different scale units